# What is the smallest f number possible?

Tags: aperture

I've quite a few questions in this regard:

1. Is there a theoretical limit?
2. What has been achieved till date?
3. What is commercially available today?
4. If there is a sudden exponential increase in price after a certain limit, what limit is that?

Comment: The two answers so far have interpreted your question differently. Can you clarify? By "smallest f number" do you mean a numerically small, but physically large, aperture (like f/1.0), or do you mean a numerically large, but physically small aperture (like f/32)?

Comment: Saying f number should not b confusing. I meant the former, like f/1.0

Answer (score 7):

1. Yes, there is a theoretical maximum of f/0.5 beyond which spherical aberrations are unavoidable. (according to the book "Applied Photographic Optics: lenses and optical systems for photography" by Sidney F. Ray)
2. The most extreme would be a f/0.33 ["Super-Q-Gigantar" by Zeiss](http://petapixel.com/2013/08/06/carl-zeiss-super-q-gigantar-40mm-f0-33-the-fastest-lens-ever-made/), but that was purely a marketing gimmick and not practically usable. The [f/0.7 (also Zeiss)](http://petapixel.com/2013/08/05/zeiss-f0-7-you-can-now-rent-two-of-the-largest-aperture-lenses-ever-made/) was actually used for a movie and is widely considered the fastest "real" lens.
3. Wikipedia lists a [number of f/0.95 lenses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_speed#Fast_lenses) as currently available. I've seen those made by SLR Magic for reasonable prices.
4. I don't think you can make a definitive statement there, it also depends a lot on the focal length and how much you're willing to compromise on optical quality.

Comment: Sidney F. Ray... how aptly named.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the f/.7 lens was actually developed for use in space for Nasa, but Stanley Kubrick got them for a movie as well.